# Why does mmap() return addresses in descending order, and malloc() in ascending order?

Tags: c, malloc, mmap

I want to know why does mmap() returns addresses in descending order, and malloc() in ascending order while both of them allocate memory in the heap?

I tried this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 6

int main()
{
    void    *ptr_mmap[NUM];
    void    *ptr_mall[NUM];

    size_t size = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
         ptr_mmap[i] = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE |
                            MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        ptr_mall[i] = malloc(size);
        printf("%d mmap ptr = %p\tmalloc ptr = %p\n", i, ptr_mmap[i],
               ptr_mall[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

example of output:

```
0 mmap ptr = 0x7fd752d6d000 malloc ptr = 0x8c3010
1 mmap ptr = 0x7fd752d6b000 malloc ptr = 0x8c3030
2 mmap ptr = 0x7fd752d6a000 malloc ptr = 0x8c3050
3 mmap ptr = 0x7fd752d69000 malloc ptr = 0x8c3070
4 mmap ptr = 0x7fd752d68000 malloc ptr = 0x8c3090
5 mmap ptr = 0x7fd752d67000 malloc ptr = 0x8c30b0
```

I was expecting both of them return addresses in ascending order since addresses grow up while allocating memory in heap. The behavior of mmap() is confusing me.

Comment: Maybe `malloc` isn't implemented using `mmap` on your (unknown) system?

Comment: And while the term "heap" is still used for dynamically allocated memory, the concept of a heap that grows up to meet a stack that grows down is old and retired since long.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude maybe, I don't know. I always thought that when you allocate memory in heap, the addresses should grow up? Isn't it true?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude where can I read about this "new" concept? Any site that I was reading is telling me that stack and heap grow up to meet each other.
Thanks!

Comment: It was common on old memory segmented systems, but haven't really been true on systems for the last 20-30 years. Books (and apparently many online tutorials) have been slow on the uptake. On a "modern" system memory can be allocated from anywhere and then mapped to any other arbitrary address.

Comment: If your system is linux, you can `cat /proc/PID/maps`. That will show some named memory areas (`[stack]`, `[heap]`, etc), some which are backed by files, and some unnamed areas. Your `mmap` chunks will be part of the latter, __not__ of the `[heap]`. But yes, quite annoyingly, many people use "heap" for anything "not on the stack".

Comment: Also, it's a pure fluke that the addresses returned by `mmap(NULL, ...)` are in any order; your OS vm may return them in ascending, descending or even in a random order, either as a security measure or in order to smoke out bugs caused by assumptions made about it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is implementation-specific and even though it appears this way on your system, it could be different for other systems. My guess is that the implementation on your system tries to keep `mmap()` allocations separated from `malloc()` allocations and thus allocates them from each end of the heap.

Answer (score -1):

For unix-like system, a process has a memory model as shown below: [image]

`malloc()` allocates memory in the heap segment, upward.  `mmmap()` allocates memory in the unallocated memory region. This region is mapped to shared memory libraries, etc.

Comment: `mmmap() allocates memory in the unallocated memory region.` - so it allocates from stack? What happens when `mmap` allocates something and I push another byte into stack? They interleave?

Comment: The stack segment is above unallocated segment. When the stack exceeded its pre-allocated stack size, it is stack overflow. When you cannot allocate any more memory from the unallocated region, `mmap()` returns -1.